# The standard deviation of the absolute error for a linear regression model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

In my linear regression model, I have *observed_values* and *predicted_values*. I want to calculate the *standard deviation of the absolute error values* in R. I think it is something like this, but not sure:

```
sd(abs(observed_values-predicted_values))
```

Is this O.K.? Is there some sort of function for that?

Comment: Yes, I obtain my predicted value from a  linear regression model. How I should use residual degree of freedom?

Comment: ok, I did it as you want not often I visit this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your linear model fit is `lmfit`, you need do:

```
n <- length(lmfit$residuals)  ## number of data / residuals
df.residual <- lmfit$df.residual  ## residual degree of freedom
abs.residual <- abs(lmfit$residuals)  ## absolute residuals
```

Now, sample standard deviation `sd(abs.residual)` is a biased estimate, because it assumes `n-1` degree of freedom in residuals. While in fact, there is only `df.residual` degree of freedom. So we need do bias correction:

```
sd(abs.residual) * sqrt((n-1) / df.residual)
```